# Unit testing network calls (failing tests) - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to write failing tests for my network calls but can't find anyway to access the connection settings from within my tests.

This code works fine for testing a success case:

```
func testRetrieveProducts() {

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("asynchronous request")

    Requests().retrieveProducts({ (products) -> () in

        // check that we have two arrays returned.
        XCTAssert(products.count == 2)
        expectation.fulfill()

        }) { (error) -> () in
        XCTFail("Request failed")
    }
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

But I've been looking for a way to test network timeouts, and incorrect data being returned.

I can probably test incorrect data by calling functions individually inside the `retrieveProducts` function and stubbing stuff out, but doing something as simple as turning off the internet is proving to be quite difficult.

I know we have access to the Network Link Conditioner, but turning this on and off for each test isn't an option.

I'd love to have access to something as simple as:

```
func testFailRetrieveProducts() {

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("asynchronous request")
    SomeNetworkClass.disableInternet()

    Requests().retrieveProducts({ (products) -> () in

        }) { (error) -> () in
        XCTAssert(error == SomeError.TimeoutError)
    }
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

Any solutions out there that can handle what I'm after, or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: you need to learn about dependency injection and inject mock network class to your request class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just mocking the network calls, which to be honest is a lot better than performing tests over an actual connection, as these can be very unreliable anyway.

**Here's my mock `NSURLSession`**

```
class MockSession: NSURLSession {

    var completionHandler:((NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)?

    static var mockResponse: (data: NSData?, urlResponse: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?)

    override class func sharedSession() -> NSURLSession {
        return MockSession()
    }

    override func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        return MockTask(response: MockSession.mockResponse, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    class MockTask: NSURLSessionDataTask {

        typealias Response = (data: NSData?, urlResponse: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?)
        var mockResponse: Response
        let completionHandler: ((NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)?

        init(response: Response, completionHandler:((NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)?) {
            self.mockResponse = response
            self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        }

        override func resume() {
            completionHandler!(mockResponse.data, mockResponse.urlResponse, mockResponse.error)
        }

    }
}
```

**Here's how I use it in a test:**

Note that you still have to use an `expectation` even though there's no network delay.

```
func testRetrieveProductsValidResponse() {

    let testBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let filepath = testBundle.pathForResource("products", ofType: "txt")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filepath!)
    let urlResponse = NSHTTPURLResponse(URL: NSURL(string: "https://anyURL.com")!, statusCode: 200, HTTPVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)

    MockSession.mockResponse = (data, urlResponse: urlResponse, error: nil)

    let requestsClass = RequestManager()
    requestsClass.Session = MockSession.self

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("ready")

    requestsClass.retrieveProducts("N/R FOR TEST", branchID: "N/R FOR TEST", products: { (products) -> () in
        XCTAssertTrue(products.count == 7)
        expectation.fulfill()
        }) { (error) -> () in
            XCTAssertFalse(error == Errors.NetworkError, "Its a network error")
            XCTAssertFalse(error == Errors.ParseError, "Its a parse error")
            XCTFail("Error not covered by previous asserts. Shouln't get to here anyway.")

            expectation.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(3.0, handler: nil)
}
```

**Finally, I have an accessible property on my RequestManager class that I can swap out with the MockSession when doing my tests.**

```
var Session = NSURLSession.self
```

Comment: what is the self.dynamicType and RequestManager() in the above test case

Comment: var Session = NSURLSession.self , where do i need to add this?.

Comment: Things are a little different now with swift 3. Will update soon and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) about Apple's Network Link Conditioner. There's a lot of presets and you can create your own custom network profile. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to throttle the network in code.

A somewhat viable alternative however is to use [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/) and model all your network events as `SignalProducers`. Then you can use the `throttle` or `wait` function, depending on your intentions.

Comment: Although the Network Link Conditioner is very useful tool, unit tests should rely on external factors as little as possible. This would help more when trying to build integration tests.